# Google Places API, Adding a place always returns INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Here's the code:

```
googleMapsAPICall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true&key=MY_KEY_HERE";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(googleMapsAPICall);
String postBody = "{\"location\":{\"lat\":-33.8669710,\"lng\":151.1958750},\"accuracy\":50.0,\"name\":\"testingjson\",\"types\":[\"other\"],\"language\":\"en\"}";
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postBody,HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(se);
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Can you see something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417764/google-places-add-place-invalid-request-error I have got same problem. What was the problem in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Answer (score 0):

The are a number of factors which can affect the response. Following are issues that I came across while adding places to my project:
1. '**type**' of place was not listed in types understood by google. Make sure that type added is given in [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).
2. The **required** types are all included in the request placed. Also make sure that it is in the right format as expected. (Please check the [request body](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place) section in 'place add' to ensure your request validity.)
3. The request sent is in the correct format and encoded with right **content type**.

Hope, this answer was useful.

Regards,
Karan